# Am getting null point exception at retrofit onResponse method

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, retrofit2

my Json:

```
{
  "status": "1",
  "login": "sucess"
}
```

this is my model class:

```
public class LoginModel {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private  String status;

    @SerializedName("login")
    @Expose
    private  String login;
...}
```

this is my interface:

```
public interface RestInterface {

    String url = "http://192.168.10.2/tourist/v1";

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/login")
    Call<LoginModel> Login(@Field("email") String email,
                           @Field("pass") String passs);
}
```

this is my call method:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(RestInterface.url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    //Creating Rest Services
    final RestInterface restInterface = retrofit.create(RestInterface.class);

    //Calling method to get check login
    Call<LoginModel> response = restInterface.Login(Email.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString());
    response.enqueue(new Callback<LoginModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<LoginModel> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());

            Email.setText("");
            Password.setText("");

            LoginModel lm = response.body();

            if ( lm.getStatus().equals("1")) {  //login Success

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login In SuccessFully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,AfterLoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            } else if (lm.getStatus().equals("0"))  // login failure
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid UserName/Password ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
            //  String merror = error.getMessage();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            }
    });
```

Am getting null point exception at line => lm.getstatus().equals(1);
It was working fine before with retrofit 1.9 then I changed it into Retrofit 2 and am getting null point exception now!

Comment: exception log please.

Comment: @Amir can you please help me with another code? it's retrofit GET request method and it directly goes to onFailure(); meaning no response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en has clarifications on on the new URL declaration pattern in Retrofit 2.0. It suggests

```
- Base URL: always ends with /
- @Url: DO NOT start with /
```

In your case the url might be interpreted as "http://192.168.10.2/login".
Try using

```
String url = "http://192.168.10.2/tourist/v1/";
```

and

```
@POST("login")
```